# Anime with students who can draw power from their "past lives"

Tags: story-identification, anime, powers, reincarnation, sword-and-sorcery

The story was something like this. The students attended an academy. They were like guardians that were able to tap into their past lives for power. The main character was kinda slow to gain power. His past life sister has a huge crush on him and a random sleepy girl also was going for him. They could use their power to change into armor and they pulled a necklace off themselves which then formed into their past lives weapon.

I watched this on YouTube the other night and now i wanna really follow it. The opening theme song video had them all fighting a dragon over a city.

Answer (score 3):

Googling for "past life weapon anime" I found [*Seiken Tsukai no World Break*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/22663/Seiken_Tsukai_no_World_Break). Description matches yours.

Those are the main heroes:

[image]

And this is the opening sequence:

Comment: I don't see a dragon in that video. Plenty of smutty fan-service, but no dragon.

Comment: @Valorum  -  first 3 seconds + 1:03. (*Is this what they call a dragon these days?*)

Comment: Oh yeah. I missed those. I enjoyed the bit where she hit it with a giant cotton bud.

Comment: @Valorum  -  honestly, I didn't have the patience to watch the whole video.

Comment: I was somewhat distracted by the fight at the start where the instructor is wearing body armour and fighting against a bunch of top-heavy teenaged girls in swimsuits.

Comment: @Valorum  -  there there, no one's blaming you...